# strange behavior when I use event.which in js

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body onkeypress = "show_key(event.which)">
<form method="post" name="my_form">
The key you pressed was:
<input type="text" name="key_display" size="2"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_key ( the_key )
{console.log(the_key);
       document.my_form.key_display.value = String.fromCharCode ( the_key );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is from here: http://www.elated.com/articles/events-and-event-handlers/

Question:

1.In front end, if i input:a, it will show:aa, why it shows double letters, I only input one a?

2.`show_key(event.which)`, here event means 'keypress', can I change the name of event? I tried to change event to e, and then in front end, I input:a, it shows:a, but in console, it also shows: `ReferenceError: e is not defined`

Comment: The reason you have "aa" doesn't seem to be in the code you show.

Comment: Yes, it's document.my_form.key_display.value = String.fromCharCode ( the_key ); and then the event it self appends it's value

Comment: @user2507818 why simply you don't give focus to the input field on document on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve event you must call the handler like this

```
<body onkeypress = "show_key(event)">
```

then inside the function

```
function show_key ( e )
{
       var the_key = e.which;
        console.log(e.which);
       document.my_form.key_display.value = String.fromCharCode ( the_key );
}
```

About the double typing it's not a double typing, first you are setting the key_Display value to the string you calculated, then, when the event has passed thought your handler it adds the symbol to the currently focused input field. More about the Events Wonderland: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture

If you only want to always focus the same input field this is an easier approach:

```
<body onload="focusMyInput">  
    <form method="post" name="my_form">
        <input type="text" id="my_input" onblur="focusMyInput" name="key_display" size="2"/>
...

var focusMyInput = function(){
   document.getElementById('my_input').focus();
}
```

This code will do that on load input#my_input will be focused, and if it get blur (looses focus) it will run the same routine to recover it.

Comment: sorry, what does this mean:`when the event has passed thought your handler it adds the symbol to the currently focused input field? `I did not understand.

Comment: ok, when an event is fired, it goes up and down the dom tree, and activates the handlers on their way. This key event activates 2, one at the document root, which you programmed, and the native input filler

Comment: You should read this http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture

Comment: Thanks, I will read it, so if I want it only show once, how could I do?

Comment: In the question you didn't explained very well I think that you want that every key press goes to that input field. Is that right?